# Getting XML attributes with Load() in JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have this code, which works:

```
$('.invest-port-thumb a').mouseenter(function() {
                $('#slider-name').load(this.href + ' cName');
});
```

Loading this XML:

```
<fragment>
    <cName cind="Industrial" stat="Active">ABC Company</cName>  
    <hq>Chicago, IL</hq>
</fragment>
```

How should I modify this code to load the `cind` attribute of `cName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery will not automatically parse the XML for you on load. But, you can use jQuery to parse the XML. Check out this page for examples: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/10/10/jquery-and-xml.html. Basically, you load the XML and perform your selections and modifications like this:

Here's a demo to get you started: if you only have one fragment and one cName in your XML, it's safe to do this:

```
var cind = $(myXML).find("fragment cName").attr("cind");
```

It appears that you are using load() to load a fragment of the XML. Instead, try loading the entire XML content to a variable, and parse the cind attribute out of it using the line of code I gave you above.

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
 $('.invest-port-thumb a').mouseenter(function() {
      $.get(this.href, function(response){
           var cind = $(response).find("fragment cName").attr("cind");
           $('#slider-name').html(cind);
      })
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But after declaring that cind variable, how can I incorporate it into the load() function syntax?

Comment: Just edited my answer to give you one possible way of doing so.

Comment: I just posted a full example.

Comment: Holy crap it works! Wow, thanks man..(I learn so much from this site every day)

Comment: This works well. but for some reason, it will not work in IE...any thoughts?

Comment: Update: This line of code: `var stat = $(response).find("fragment cName").attr("stat");` works when used, but this line doesn't: `var cName = $(response).find("fragment cName");`  (Only in IE, firefox works fine)

Comment: This line:
     var cName = $(response).find("fragment cName");
returns a jQuery object, not a value.